# I would like to use XIRR function with Array Formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIS56.png)

i would like to calculate XIRR for every row in the column E. just for illustration purpose i have shown data in 8 rows, in real situation i may have more than 5000 rows and do not want to use XIRR function for every row, instead looking if possible to use Array formula. ideally i may only want to set the XIRR function with Array formula at cell E2 and populate the XIRR value for the entire column E. thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Is this post https://superuser.com/questions/260527 helpful, by calculating `=XIRR(C2:D2,A2:B2)` and afterwards autofill the rest of the rows?

Comment: whats the xirr formula you are using for single row?